# prevent scroll event from "overflowing" into the body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have section of a document with style `overflow-y: scroll;` Within this element, I can scroll. The problem is when the bottom of this section is reached, the scroll events are applied to the document and the page is propelled rapidly downward. I need to allow this section to scroll until the end of the section, wherein the event is halted. Then, once the user initiates another scroll event, the document is allowed to scroll as usual.

edit: Heres some pieces of the code I've tried.

```
$('#activity_widget').bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
    var scrollTo = null;

    if (e.type == 'mousewheel') {
      console.log(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta);

        if (last_y == e.screenY){
          // alert('halt!');
          scrollTo = (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta * -1);
        }
        last_y = e.screenY;

        // scrollTo = (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta * -1);
    }

    if (scrollTo) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).scrollTop(scrollTo + $(this).scrollTop());
    }
});
```

Comment: can we get some code?

Answer (score 0):

You *can* do like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/1vb8yh0L/

The sad part about this is that you will override the users scroll amount, most people don't change this, but in your OS you can change how many rows each step on the scroll wheel shall be worth. It might be possible to get this information with javascript, but i do not know how. The other thing you could do is to keep track of difference between this events $(this).scrollTop() and the previous and store that as an absolute amount and use it as your scroll amount. You will have to handle what happens if the user scroll once with the mouse, then with the scrollbar, then with the mouse again, that could become rather complex so i have omitted this from the example.

The script (without fiddle):

```
$('#activity_widget').bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    var scrollAmount = 70;

    if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta >= 0) {
        $(this).scrollTop(scrollTop - scrollAmount);
    }
    else {
        $(this).scrollTop(scrollTop + scrollAmount);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic should be as simple as possible:

1. if mouse is over your container and it scrolls your container - scroll it (do not prevent event, otherwise you should emulate scroll manually with scrollTop), but set flag to prevent document scrolling if top/bottom is reached
2. if mouse is over your container and it cannot be scrolled in scroll direction (top/bottom is reached) - check if document can be scrolled. If it cannot - prevent scroll event.
3. in both cases you should reset flag after some time to allow user to continue scrolling document

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/1vb8yh0L/1/) on jsFiddle:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var allowDocumentScroll = true;
    var timer = 0;

    function enableDocumentScrollAfterPause() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            allowDocumentScroll = true;
        }, 300);
    }

    $('.content').on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function (event) {
        var delta = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta * -1 || event.originalEvent.detail; // - up, + down
        var element = $(this);
        var maxScroll = element.prop('scrollHeight') - element.height();

        if ((delta < 0 && $(this).scrollTop() > 0) || (delta > 0 && $(this).scrollTop() < maxScroll)) {
            allowDocumentScroll = false;
            enableDocumentScrollAfterPause();
            return;
        }

        if (!allowDocumentScroll) {
            event.preventDefault();
            enableDocumentScrollAfterPause();
        }
    });
});
```